# Filtering contents in Views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I've got content-type with 3 integer field. I use Views module to display contents. I've got search. I'd like to create input in that search. After filling that input and entering I want to display contents whose at least one field is equal given value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like exposed filters are what you're looking for. Just check for the "Expose" control when you're edited any filter item in your view.

Comment: I've got 3 field in custom content-type and I want to have got one input in search. Later I'd like to choose contents whose at least one from three field value is equal value filiing by user.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand yours idea. Could you give me some directions?